# Unable to resolve lmjoin in the winapi::um

Tags: winapi, rust

I am trying to use the NetGetJoinInformation function and I cannot resolve it from the winapi-rs crate.

Here is the code and the compiler output.

```rust
use winapi::um::lmjoin::NetGetJoinInformation;
use winapi::um::PNETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS;
use winapi::um::winnt::LPWSTR;
use winapi::um::winnt::LPCWSTR;

fn foo() {
    let mut lpServer: LPCWSTR = 0 as *mut u16;
    let mut DomainName: LPWSTR = 0 as *mut u16;
    let mut pNetJoinStatus: PNETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS = 0;
    NetGetJoinInformation(0, &DomainName, &pNetJoinStatus);
}
```

Compiler output:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `winapi::um::lmjoin`                                                                                                                                                               
 --> src/foo.rs:2:17                                                                                                                                                                                      
  |
2 | use winapi::um::lmjoin::NetGetJoinInformation;
  |                 ^^^^^^ could not find `lmjoin` in `um`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `winapi::um::PNETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS`
 --> src/foo.rs:3:5
  |
3 | use winapi::um::PNETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `PNETSETUP_JOIN_STATUS` in `um`
```

I am of course compiling for windows.

I have no idea why it happens. I tried to trick with features but nothing seemed to work. I think it might be a problem with the crate. I already posted an issue on the github repository in case it was really a problem with the library and not a problem between the chair and the keyboard. Any clues ?
Thanks a lot !

EDIT:
Here is the Cargo.toml

```ini
[package]
name = "foo"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
winapi = {version="0.3.9", features=["winuser"]}
```

Comment: Please include your `Cargo.toml`

Comment: I am using the latest crate version. I edited my post.

Comment: Instead of trying to "trick" with features, have you tried enabling the `lmjoin` feature without which that module won't compile?

Comment: [Enable the `lmjoin` feature.](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.9/src/winapi/um/mod.rs.html#141)